Georeference 3D data generated using BlenderGIS
I generated a 3D model (terrain + extruded buildings) using BlenderGIS,and I was wondering if I could integrate them into an ifc project having the right georeferencing using BlenderBIM. The problem is, BlenderGIS does not georeference the model, but only stores the coordinates of the origin of the geoscene. So when I assign ifc classes to my 3d objects, they maintain their relative coordinates to the origin of the scene, and not the coordinates of the GIS data from where they originated.

This Q&A site can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons. BlenderBIM and BlenderGIS are not part of Blender and are authored by third-parties so questions about them are off-topic here. You'll have to ask on their web site or a forum discussing them elsewhere.

understood, have a nice day !
